# List to Jagged Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

Now I want to add this to a Jagged Array

```
int[][] A = new int[][] { list.ToArray() };
```

This code on top is ok, but the problem is that all values in the list are add in the first block!
Well, then, this will be solved:

```
int[] x1 = list.ToArray();
int[][] A = new int[][] { new[] { x1[0] }, new[] { x1[1] }, new[] { x1[2] }, new[] { x1[3] } };
```

But (the code above) I've done this manually now, that's just the first four indexes I've of list put in the array..

How can I add entire list (all indexes) to my jagged array (with circles or other methods).

Comment: FYI Thats not a 2D array, thats a jagged array (i.e array of arrays)

Comment: Can’t you create a List<YourObject> which has two int properties ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to build. Are you trying to build a jagged array in which the first row has 1 element, the next row has 2 elements, the next 3, etc? Please edit your question. Given a `List<int>` that has 10 elements, show the `int[][]` that you want as output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a projection.

This will iterate through the list, creating a new array with the sole value of the current iteration, and then end by creating an array of all of those arrays.

```
int[][] A = list.Select(i => new[] { i }).ToArray();
```

As an aside, and [as [@maccettura] notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660797/list-to-array-2d-in-c-sharp#comment86331260_49660797), this is a jagged array (where each member of the array is also an array itself).

Comment: @nicomp: It really is. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays: "A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays."